# ffmpeg segment muxer produces unplayable HEVC video outputs

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to process streaming video data from a usb webcam using ffmpeg. the process involves encoding the raw data into hevc format. Up to this point I am able to do. 
But now, I want to slice the processed data in chunks of 10 seconds and save it in a separate file. This should repeat until I kill/interrupt the process manually.

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video1 -f segment -segment_times 10 -c:v hevc cam_1_%02d.mp4
```

the above code does create multiple files but only the first file is readable using vlc; other files look corrupt.

And while I was running the command, I could see the following messages:-

```
Stream mapping:  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264)) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help Past duration 0.601555 too largeN/A time=00:00:14.63 bitrate=N/A dup=11 drop=0      Past duration
0.601463 too large Past duration 0.601555 too largeN/A time=00:00:15.16 bitrate=N/A dup=11 drop=0     Past duration 0.601585 too large
    Last message repeated 1 times Past duration 0.601646 too large Past duration 0.601677 too large Past duration 0.601707 too largeN/A time=00:00:15.66 bitrate=N/A dup=11 drop=0
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why is this tagged `python` ? And what is the programming aspect ? It seems to be just an issue with using the `ffmpeg` command line tool ?

Comment: eh, we could use ffmpy module in python to do the same thing. If anyone knew about that; it could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-reset_timestamps 1` output option. From the [segment muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment):

> Reset timestamps at the beginning of each segment, so that each segment
>   will start with near-zero timestamps. It is meant to ease the playback
>   of the generated segments. May not work with some combinations of
>   muxers/codecs. It is set to 0 by default.

Also, consider changing `-segment_times` to `-segment_time` because you are a single time value.

Comment: Thank you!! that solved the problem. But there is something wrong in the segmentation. I am giving the slice time to be every 10s but each video is only 8s in length. Any idea about that?

Comment: @DeepakNellurvalappil Probably worth asking that as a new question at [su]. I'll see it there. Make sure to show your actual ffmpeg command and the complete console output/log from that command.